# bash double bracket issue

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm very new to bash scripting and am running into an issue when using double brackets. I can't seem to get them to work at all in Ubuntu Server 11.10. My script below is in if_test.sh.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "14"=="14" ]]; then 
    echo "FOO"
fi
```

When I run this simple shell script the output I get is: if_test.sh: 5: [[: not found

It seems that I'm running GNU bash version 4.2.10 after running bash --version from the terminal. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, without the spaces, this isn't comparing `14` to `14`, it's checking if the string `14==14` is empty. It would give the exact same result with `[[ "11"=="99" ]]`, since that string isn't empty either.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The problem lies in your script invocation. You're issuing:

```
$ sudo sh if_test.sh
```

On Ubuntu systems, `/bin/sh` [is `dash`, not `bash`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh), and `dash` does not support the double bracket keyword (or didn't at the time of this posting, I haven't double-checked). You can solve your problem by explicitly invoking `bash` instead:

```
$ sudo bash if_test.sh
```

Alternatively, you can make your script executable and rely on the [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29):

```
$ chmod +x if_test.sh
$ sudo ./if_test.sh
```

Also note that, when used between double square brackets, `==` is a [pattern matching operator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching), not the equality operator. If you want to test for equality, you can either use `-eq`:

```
if [[ "14" -eq "14" ]]; then 
    echo "FOO"
fi
```

Or [double parentheses](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html):

```
if (( 14 == 14 )); then 
    echo "FOO"
fi
```

Comment: Strange, the `[[` keyword has been supported since version 2.02 of `bash`. How are you executing your script? Maybe you end up using a different shell...

Comment: I'm executing it with: sudo sh if_test.sh

Comment: It seems I needed to execute it just as ./if_test.sh. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I had spent the last hour trying to figure out why this didn't work.

Comment: Of course `==` is supported inside `[[...]]` --  http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-g_t_005b_005b-57 -- it is a pattern matching operator, not an equality operator.

Comment: @glenn, you're right, I probably was confusing with `[`. I'll update my answer with that information and your link. Thanks for the heads-up :)

Answer (score 10):

My answer doesn't apply to @lots_of_questions's question specifically, but you can also run into this problem if you have the wrong specifier at the top of your script:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [[ ... ]]
...
```

You should change that to

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ... ]]
...
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you are new to scripting, you may be unaware that `[[` is a bashism.   You may not even know what a bashism is, but both answers given so far are leading you down a path towards a stunted scripting future by promoting their use.

To check if a variable matches a string in any flavor of Bourne shell, you can do `test $V = 14`  If you want to compare integers, use `test $V -eq 14`.  The only difference is that the latter will generate an error if $V does not look like an integer.  There are good reasons to quote the variable (`test "$V" = 14`), but the quotes are often unnecessary and I believe are the root cause of a common confusion, since `"14"=="14"` is identical to `"14==14"` where it is more obvious that '==' is not being used as an operator.

There are several things to note: use a single '=' instead of '==' because not all shells recognize '==', the `[` command is identical to `test` but requires a final argument of `]` and many sh coding guidelines recommend using `test` because it often generates more understandable code, `[[` is only recognized by a limited number of shells (this is your primary problem, as your shell does not appear to recognize `[[` and is looking for a command of that name.  This is surprising if your shebang does indeed specify `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh`).