# Heroku Toolbelt PPA update check failing

Tags: heroku-toolbelt

For the past day or so, the Ubuntu repository for Heroku Toolbelt has been reporting the following:

```
Failed to fetch http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu/./Packages  302  Moved Temporarily [IP: 23.21.198.2 80]
```

What gives?

Answer (score 2):

I assume some configuration on the Heroku servers is broken. If I edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/heroku.list` and replace the existing line

```
deb http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu ./
```

with

```
deb https://s3.amazonaws.com/heroku-toolbelt/ apt/
```

I can run `apt-get update` but I still can't download any packages.

I assume this is a temporary issue, but I've reported it to the Heroku support just to be sure.

**EDIT**: According to the Heroku support this is caused by a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. Changing the line in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/heroku.list` to use https should fix the issue. I can't verify it atm, though. See also the related [pull request](https://github.com/heroku/toolbelt/pull/70)

Comment: I can confirm that changing the address to https (`https://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu`) make it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are experiencing the same problem posted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199860/e-unable-to-locate-package-heroku-toolbelt). I was able to work around the problem and installing the heroku toolbelt today on an Ubuntu 13-based system by installing the [standalone toolkit](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/standalone) rather than the Ubuntu/Debian bundle.  The standalone won't automatically install Git and Foreman, but will get you running with the toolkit.  You'll also need to have Ruby installed before executing the script below.  I used apt to install a recent version.

I encountered some errors on my Ubuntu-based distro because [on Ubuntu systems /bin/sh is dash, not bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666102/bash-double-bracket-issue), which you can avoid by modifying heroku's script after grabbing it to explicitly call bash:

Get heroku's install script

```
wget -q https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh
```

Edit line 10 to use bash instead of sh and save:

```
sudo bash <<SCRIPT
```

Execute the script (using sh or bash, it doesn't matter)

```
sh install.sh
```

Pay attention to the script's exit message and add the heroku CLI to your PATH (assuming it's not already there)

```
$ echo 'PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
```

You'll have to logout/login to the load the PATH change and execute heroku without using the full path.

Comment: using bash instead of sh mattered to me in ubuntu 14.04