# E: Unable to locate package heroku-toolbelt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, linux-mint

I am trying to install the `Heroku Toolbelt` on Linux Mint 15 Olivia (x86-64)

When i try to run the standard command for installing on Debian machines:

> wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh

I get:

> W: Failed to fetch http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu/./Packages  302  Moved Temporarily [IP: 23.21.198.2 80]
>
> ...
>
> E: Unable to locate package heroku-toolbelt

I have also got the `heroku.list` repo in my `etc/apt/sources/`:

> deb http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu ./

When i try to add the repo again with:

> sudo apt-add-repository 'deb http://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/ubuntu ./'

I get:

> Cannot add PPA: 'No JSON object could be decoded'.

And it seems i'm not the first person with this error on Mint 15 while trying to add repositories.

Comment: I literally just had this happen to me, on Linux Mint, also 15 minutes ago. (We should hang out sometime.) It looks like the version of apt-get Mint uses doesn't handle HTTP redirects? I tried messing around with a lot of things, but couldn't get this to work. Good luck.

Comment: If you find the answer please let me know, bonus points and friendship guaranteed :D

I'm still searching for a solution

Comment: Maybe it really did move temporarily and we should wait? (The 302 Error)

Comment: Seems we are not the only ones with the problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194283/heroku-toolbelt-ppa-update-check-failing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect this issue may indeed be temporary, but if you need the heroku toolbelt installed now, you can install the standalone client instead of the ubuntu/debian bundle.

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
```

On an Ubuntu-based distro, however, the above will likely throw some errors:

```
sh: 7: [[: not found
sh: 29: [[: not found
Installation complete
```

This is because [on Ubuntu systems /bin/sh is dash, not bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666102/bash-double-bracket-issue). You could either get the script and modify it to use bash instead of sh (sh is called within the script, just changing sh to bash in the command above won't suffice), or, you could ignore the errors and just do what the error-ing portion of the script instructs you to do:

Add the Heroku CLI to your PATH using:

```
echo 'PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile
```

You'll need to logout/login again to register the path addition, or just execute heroku directly in the mean time:

```
/usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku
```