# Change the commit author of commits starting with a pattern (in message)

Tags: git

I have a repository where there are some (actually a lot) commits generated by a program that look like:

```
Adding new domains: example.com
```

It happened (because of a wrong configuration) that these commits were made in the name of a co-worker. Now, I want to change these commits author:

```
Some Bot <bot@example.com>
```

Github has a public script posted [here](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/) to change the commits filtered by an old author. In this case, I want to change the author of commits whom messages start with a pattern: *Adding new domains:*. How can I do that?

Comment: You should probably just write a script that parses the output `git log`

Comment: @ssdecontrol Maybe can you help? I'd use the `git filter-branch` if that's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I think you will have to use the [`--commit-filter`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) filter.  This is the only way to get your hands on both the commit message (from stdin) and the environment variables at the same time.  The new script will have to completely replicate all the functionality of [`commit-tree`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree).  Fortunately, it won't look all that different from the GitHub script you linked.

First, read the *entire* commit message into a Bash variable:

```
commitmsg=$(cat)
```

Now get the first line of it and test whether it matches:

```
firstline=$(echo "$commitmsg" | head -n1 | grep "Adding new domains:")
if [ "$firstline" ]; then
```

We matched the commit message, so do the regular replacement, like in GitHub's script.

```
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
```

Now we must call `git commit-tree`.  The commit message is provided on stdin, just like we got it.  Since our script is acting as a `commit-tree` surrogate, we need to pass all arguments on as well.  The environment variables we (may have) modified will take care of themselves.

```
echo "$commitmsg" | git commit-tree "$@"
```

This will emit the hash onto stdout, just like we are required to do.  At this point, we're done!

Here's a copy of the completed script.  YMMV, of course, but I tested it and it works fine.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

git filter-branch --commit-filter '

CORRECT_NAME="Your Correct Name"
CORRECT_EMAIL="your-correct-email@example.com"

commitmsg=$(cat)

firstline=$(echo "$commitmsg" | head -n1 | grep "Adding new domains:")
if [ "$firstline" ]; then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi

echo "$commitmsg" | git commit-tree "$@"

' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

Comment: Thanks! It's pretty readable what you did, however instead of ` "$firstline" = "Adding new domains: example.com"` I need to have *if commit message starts with `Adding new domains:`* -- because the domain values are different. PS: Maybe it would be better to include the whole script here. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh gotcha, missed that.  Good points.  Everything should be working with the edits I made.

Comment: I'm getting errors like *Rewrite 41...a9 (86/1243)git commit-tree: 56: git commit-tree: [[: not found*

Comment: Hmm, are you using GNU bash? I haven't tried it on sh and other bashes, and I don't know what the feature matrix for `[[` is.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 -- `GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

Comment: Ahh, here's your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9666169/1830736. I bet Git is invoking `/bin/sh`.  I wonder if putting a shebang `#!/bin/bash` at the top of the quoted script would help.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `firstline=$(echo "$commitmsg" | head -n1 | grep "Adding new domains:")`, then check this for emptiness with `if [ "$firstline" ]` (thereby avoiding Bashisms).

Comment: This fixed the problem. It's working! Thanks a lot. Don't forget to update your script. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`--env-filter`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_options) and [`rev-list`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) arguments (`--grep=<pattern>` in this case) to limit the commits to the ones you want to modify:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

git filter-branch --env-filter '

CORRECT_NAME="Your Correct Name"
CORRECT_EMAIL="your-correct-email@example.com"

export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"

' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags --grep='Adding new domains'
```

You could save this script with the *git-* prefix and place it somewhere in your PATH, eg. `/usr/local/bin/git-change-author` (make sure it's executable) and run it from your repository as:

```
git change-author
```

Don't forget to `git push --force` since you rewrote the history.

Comment: Huh, cool. Where is `--grep` documented? I didn't see it in the `filter-branch` man page.

Comment: @Calin This did something, but didn't change the author of these commits. After running the script I got `WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged`. Any ideas?

Comment: Try without the ':' in --grep, I updated the script.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried it on a commit that had the subject you mentioned and it worked without any problems. Try `--all` instead of `--branches --tags`, although I think it won't make a difference. Maybe you already changed the author on the previous run?

Comment: @Calin Used the other script, but I'm voting you up too! :) Thanks both!

Comment: Thanks, don't forget to `git push -f` (force) since you rewrote the history.