# bash script maybe syntax error not sure trying a until loop

Tags: python, bash, powershell, wake-on-lan

Hello guys i am trying to code a wol script for my server. Wich the raspberry pi executes everytime when its booting.

I guess its a syntax error but i dont now the solution so i am asking you.
I am getting an error in line 5 but no clue how to correct it.

```
#!/bin/bash

nas=[ping -c 1 192.192.168.222.5 &> /dev/null ]

until [ $nas = "1" ];do
python wol.py
sleep 2
nas=[ping -c 1 192.192.168.222.5 &> /dev/null ]
done
```

the wol.py is the script from marc balmar which sending the wol package

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding: utf8

# Wake-On-LAN
#
# Copyright (C) 2002 by Micro Systems Marc Balmer
# Written by Marc Balmer, marc@msys.ch, http://www.msys.ch/
# Modified by saarnu for nerdoskop.wordpress.com
# This code is free software under the GPL

import struct, socket, time, os

def WakeOnLan(ethernet_address):

  # Construct a six-byte hardware address

  addr_byte = ethernet_address.split(':')
  hw_addr = struct.pack('BBBBBB', int(addr_byte[0], 16),
    int(addr_byte[1], 16),
    int(addr_byte[2], 16),
    int(addr_byte[3], 16),
    int(addr_byte[4], 16),
    int(addr_byte[5], 16))

  # Build the Wake-On-LAN "Magic Packet"...

  msg = '\xff' * 6 + hw_addr * 16

  # ...and send it to the broadcast address using UDP
  time.sleep(5)
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
  s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
  s.sendto(msg, ('<broadcast>', 9))
  s.close()

WakeOnLan('C8:60:00:6D:CF:54') # MAC-Adresse der DiskStation
```

I wrote a similar code in powershell it was a lot easier i am literally trying to copy it or translate it to bash.

```
$NAS = test-connection -count 1 -quiet 192.168.222.5
if ($NAS -like "False"){
do
{
$Mac = "C8:60:00:6D:CF:54"
$MacByteArray = $Mac -split "[:-]" | ForEach-Object { [Byte] "0x$_"}
[Byte[]] $MagicPacket = (,0xFF * 6) + ($MacByteArray  * 16)
$UdpClient = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient
$UdpClient.Connect(([System.Net.IPAddress]::Broadcast),7)
$UdpClient.Send($MagicPacket,$MagicPacket.Length)
$UdpClient.Close()
Start-Sleep -s 5
$NAS = test-connection -count 1 -quiet 192.168.222.5
}
until
(
$NAS -like "True"
)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Firstly, use http://www.shellcheck.net to fix your syntax issues in script.

Your syntaxes for command-substitution is wrong, with that fix and using exit  code of `ping` directly in the `until-loop`

```
until ping -c 1 192.192.168.222.5 &> /dev/null
do
    python wol.py
    sleep 2
done
```

should solve your problem. The `man` page of `ping` says

> If ping does not receive any reply packets at all it will exit with code 1. If a packet count and deadline are both specified, and fewer than count packets are received by the time the deadline has arrived, it will also exit with code 1. On other error it exits with code 2. Otherwise it exits with code 0. This makes it possible to use the exit code to see if a host is alive or not.

Comment: So simple, thank you it is working now and with less code

Comment: @SelimAkca: Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Hey there are a couple of mistakes in your bash script, not just one.

```
#!/bin/bash

# This is a silent ping. The output is redirected to /dev/null. The only visible
# change in user-land will be the exit code, available as $?.
# The exit code "0" means success, the exit code "1" means some error.

ping -c 1 192.192.168.222.5 &> /dev/null

# You need double round parenthesis here to evaluate a comparison.
# Also a comparison, as almost everywhere in programming, is "==" instead of "=".
until (( $? == "0" ));
    do
    python wol.py
    sleep 2
    # There is the silent ping again. Updating $?.
    ping -c 1 192.192.168.222.5 &> /dev/null
done
```

For the exit code see:
[Exit Shell Script Based on Process Exit Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90418/exit-shell-script-based-on-process-exit-code)

And for the different parenthesis/brackets see either the really good bash manual via `man bash`, [How to use double or single brackets, parentheses, curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/how-to-use-double-or-single-bracket-parentheses-curly-braces) or https://stackoverflow.com/a/9666169/7236811.