# Tomcat can't be run because of errors in catalina.sh

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, tomcat

I use Tomcat 9.0.41 which comes bundled with an application. After the application was installed I try to run Tomcat by using the provided scripts. But those scripts throw a lot of errors like this:

```
./catalina.sh: 281: [[: not found
./catalina.sh: 286: [[: not found
./catalina.sh: 291: [[: not found
./catalina.sh: 295: [[: not found
./catalina.sh: 300: [[: not found
./catalina.sh: 305: [[: not found
./catalina.sh: 310: [[: not found
```

The line with the `if` is line `281`:

```
#!/bin/sh
...
if [[ -n $SERVER_CERT_PATH && $SERVER_CERT_PATH != "" ]]; then
  SRV_KS_PATH=$SERVER_CERT_PATH
fi
```

I checked several posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666102/bash-double-bracket-issue) about scripts and the behaviour of `[[` but haven't found a reason why these messages appear.
The environment I run all this in is Ubuntu 20.04, the `test` utility exists.

When I force to use bash by calling `bash catalina.sh` I don't see any errors. But for nested scripts like `startup.sh` which inside calls `catalina.sh` this doesn't work.

Is there a way to fix this ? I don't want to edit the scripts if possible.
Perhaps I need to change some OS setting ? (which would make this more of a UNIX SE or askubuntu question)

Comment: The standard [`catalina.sh`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/master/bin/catalina.sh) script is POSIX compliant and does not contain those [_bashisms_](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306111/381289). How did you install Tomcat?

Comment: The scripts need to be modified to use only `sh` syntax, like @PiotrP.Karwasz.  You could try just changing the first line with `#!/bin/bash`.  But remember that using non-standard scripts expose you for the future, if you patch or upgrade your tomcat (and you should!).

Comment: @Nic3500 We receive the script bundled with an application sold by Microfocus. Whenever they update I would have to apply the same changes.

Comment: If the application was sold to your company with a failing start script, I would call up support and demand something that works.  If they cannot fix it quickly, I would reconsider having future business with these guys, their QA is seriously lacking.

Comment: @Nic3500 We already created a ticket because of this. And asked why they changed that script. Btw: it works quite fine on CentOS, RHEL and Amazon Linux which they officially support